# How can I tell if my Application is resumed from background?

Tags: android

I want to lock my application when it goes in background and 
when it resumes I want to display my own lock screen. The lock screen is an Activity of my application.

After successfully entring password the user can see the resumed Activity 
else he can't.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve that if you have a global Activity "MyActivity" and all the activities extend from it.

Then you override onPause and onStop methods on "MyActivity"

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    setLockStatus(false);
}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    setLockStatus(true);
}
```

and:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    checkLockScreen();
}
```

EDIT: Obviously you need to create the methods setLockStatus and checkLockScreen and do whatever you want (like save the status on sharedPreferences).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am starting second activity from first activity in that case in onPause() method of first activity a flag will be true and when second activity will resume at that time the flag will be true so that it will open unlock screen That means that when ever my activity will pause it will ask for unlock so this is not solution as my need.

Comment: Do you want your application to be locked only when it comes from the background? when the application go to the background both onPause and onStop will be called, leaving lockStatus to "true", but if you move from one Activity to another, onPause will be called, leaving the lock to false. I pasted that code because I came with the same problem as you faced and that was my solution.

Comment: I think you understand wrong when you start another activity then 1) first activity will pause.2) second activity create,start and resume. 3) first activity will stop and/or destroy

Comment: You answered yourself.. 1) onPause > lock off 2) 2nd Activity Resume >  is lock enabled? NO 3) if you destroy your 1st Activity (it's not mandatory) it doesn't matter because your activity is already unlocked.. but that's the good thing of SO you can choose the best solution for you between the answers..

Comment: I can't get you how my problem will solved if I set flag in onPause method because it will call 3 times 1) on Home button pressed 2) second activity comes above first activity 3) third application comes above my application so how I can distinguish them ?

Comment: Well, in my case, I tested the situations you mentioned and it worked. When I move within the application the lock screen never show up. If I press the home button and then click again on the app (or via long press the home button) the lock screen appears. You can check the results adding Log.d lines to your functions like I did before I figured out how to make it work.

Comment: SERPRO, thanks so much. This idea is awesome and I would never have thought of it.

Answer (score 13):

The principal problem is that you have to get a specific behavior when you start an `Activity` from the background. `onPause()` and `onResume()` are called every time you switch between `Activities` and not just when you minimize your application. To get around that you can get the currently running tasks from the `ActivityManager` and compare their package name to the one of your application:

```
private boolean isApplicationInBackground() {
    final ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = manager.getRunningTasks(1);
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
        final ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
        return !topActivity.getPackageName().equals(getPackageName());
    }    
    return false;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
public boolean wasPaused = false;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if(isApplicationInBackground()) {
        wasPaused = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(wasPaused) {
        lockScreen();
        wasPaused = false;
    }
}
```

And that is it! I recommend you implement this in a base `Activity` which all your other `Activities` inherent from.

Comment: Why not use onRestart()?

Comment: ActivityManager.getRunningTasks() appears to be deprecated.

Comment: ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()  is deprecated as of Lollipop.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone that is interested, if I understand your question correctly, I was looking into similar functionality and wasn't happy with what I found. I wanted to determine when the activity was being resumed from the background vs. when it was being resumed from a called activity.

I ended up utilizing a boolean flag that get's set from startActivity that will allow the calling Activity to determine whether or not it is resuming from the called Activity or from the background. Something like this

```
private static boolean RESUME_FROM_ACTIVITY;

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(!RESUME_FROM_ACTIVITY){
        // do what you want like lock the screen
    }
    RESUME_FROM_ACTIVITY = false;
}

@Override
public void startActivity(Intent intent){
    RESUME_FROM_ACTIVITY = true;
    super.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Because of the way that Android handles statics and the activity stack [(read more in this blog post)](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html), this should work conceptually. A bit more of an explanation, the static *should* be one of the last things that gets cleared from memory when your app is running *if* the heap space gets too large. The activity will not be destroyed without the stack itself being destroyed, so onResume will be called and it will check the static flag to see if it is coming from another activity or from the background.

The static is likely even overkill, as again the activity itself won't be destroyed and it's globals will be held as long as possible. This is only conceptual and we are still in the middle of stress testing it, but it is an option. If we find any issues I will update this post.

Answer (score 2):

Your activity has an `onResume()` callback in its life cycle. Simple override this and do what you need to do.

Comment: But how can I know that my activity is resumed after background or by starting from another activity ?

Comment: What do you mean "after background"? If you mean you want to know if it paused due to launching another of your own activities, you must add that logic to your code around the point you `startActivity()`... however if doing that, you also must communicate between your activities so you know when they have paused as well; their resume logic will have to do the same sort of re-lock.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should override methods onResume and onPause

see **[this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)** and you will get it :)

in your activity you can have a flag like 
boolean locked;

and in onPause you can set this to true.
And every time in critical places you can check the state of this flag and if it is true then you show you unlock activity, after a success in unlocking then set the flag to false.

Comment: I am starting second activity from first activity in that case in onPause() method of first activity a flag will be true and when second activity will resume at that time the flag will be true so that it will open unlock screen That means that when ever my activity will pause it will ask for unlock so this is not solution as my need.

Comment: yes, if you code that way you will be prompted to unlock every time when onPause will be called

Comment: Instead, the case is ok if you disable the flag in onResume in each of the lockable activities. The lock activity has its own check and not part of the lockable activity, if it is launched it means that no new activities have been started after onStop.